# NSDateFormatter date problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using the Tapku library for Date purpose. After selecting the date by using the DateFormatter. I am getting the date, It is working fine in India.But When client(US) checking the dates it gives the one day before the selected Date.

Comment: Have you tried setting the time zone for the date formatter you are using? Something like this: `[dtFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];`

Comment: Yep, you need to play with the time zone, but like as not (if you're just doing dates and not times) you want to set the time zone to GMT/UCT (rather than your current zone, which is probably the default) so that an NSDate object is converted to a character date without regard to time zone.

Answer (score 1):

i have got same problem but solution is set the gmtTimeZone in your code.like this

in following method..
 - (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d 
{

```
  NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];///set GMT Time

NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
[df setTimeZone:gmt];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSString *dateNTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [df stringFromDate:d]];
NSLog(@"%@",dateNTime);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to get locale and set default device/system locale. Refer Apple documentation
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html